# ERR: The baseZIndex property is deprecated since v14.2.0, use overlayOptions property instead

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, deprecated, primeng-dropdowns

I have an Angular Project, now after some version upgrades. The project started giving some deprecation warnings as can be shown in the image below:

[image]

I think this is due to the primeng version upgrade to: `"primeng": "^15.0.0"` from 12.0.0. Also, I am not able to find any official migration guide for the Angular PrimeNg

Here is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.3",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.7",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@schematics/angular": "^9.1.0",
    "@sentry/angular": "^7.26.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.26.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.24",
    "apollo-angular": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "1.10.28",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.10.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.3",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.44.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.44.0",
    "ajv": "^7.2.4",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^7.1.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.29",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "apollo-angular": {
      "@angular/core": "^15.0.0"
    }
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint"
    }
  }
```

Your response will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)